# NameError when running Python code in shell

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking to run the function get_cords() in a shell to get the current mouse position, however, I get an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'get_cords' is not defined
```

Here is the code

```
import ImageGrab
import os
import time
import win32api, win32con

x_pad = 464
y_pad = 366


def screenGrab():
    box = (x_pad + 1, y_pad + 1, x_pad + 640, y_pad + 481)
    im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\full_snap__' + str(int(time.time())) + '.png', 'PNG')


def main():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


def leftClick():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
    print "Click."


def leftDown():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    print "left Down"


def leftUp():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    print "left Release"


def mousePos(cord):
    win32api.SetCursorPos(x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1])


def get_cords():
    x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    x = x - x_pad
    y = y - y_pad
    print x, y
```

Yes, I am running the shell within the project folder. I am also running Python 2.7.13 and use PyCharm.

Comment: Ddid you `import` the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this answer will ever be relevant to anyone else, but what worked for me was the following:

```
>>> import file_name
>>> file_name.function_name()
```

and VOILA!